# A random number of random variables, (expectation help)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

everyone

First a definition let $S_N = X_1 + X_2 \cdots + X_N$ where $X_i$'s are random variables and $N$ is also a random variable. Also assume that the $X_i$'s(integer valued),independent identically distributed.

The statement is:

If $E[N] < \infty$ and $E\lvert X \rvert < \infty$, then $E[S_n] = E[X]\cdot E[N]$

so the proof begins like:

$\bf{(1)}$ $\enspace E[S_N]= \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} E(S_N\mid N = n)\cdot P(N = n) = ... $

i won't write the whole proof ,since my question is about a detail above ,namely ; is $E[S_N]$ actually a function of the random variable $N$ ?  $E[S_N] = f(N)$ then $\bf{(1)}$ above makes sense(for me), otherwise i don't understand, then i must have missed some definition about expectations.

Comment: $E[S_N]$ is an element of $\mathbb R$. So $E[S_N]=f(N)$ is true for the **constant** function $f$ prescribed by $r\mapsto E[S_N]$.

Comment: You don't really need the $X_i$ to be integer-valued, but $N$ needs to take on (positive or non-negative) integer values.

Answer (score 2):

$S_N$ is a function of the random variable $N$ (as well as of the $X_i$), but $E[S_N]$ is not; it is a real number.

$E[S_N\mid N]$ is a function of the random variable $N$ but not of the $X_i$. This random variable $E[S_N\mid N]$ takes on value $nE[X]$ whenever $N$ has value $n$.

The right side of your $(1)$ is an application of the law of the unconscious statistician which allows one to compute the expected value of $E[S_N\mid N]$ using the distribution of $N$. That the *expected value* of the random variable $E[S_N\mid N]$ is the same as the *expected value* of $S_N$ is called the law of iterated expectation.

Of course, all this requires finite expectations in order for it all to work.

Answer (score 1):

No, $\mathbb{E}[S_N]$ is not a function of the random variable $N$; it's just a real number, like any old expectation.

The problem you have asked is an interesting one and motivates the definition of the sample space $\Omega$. You might be thinking: since $\mathbb{E}[S_n]$ is just a number, and $\mathbb{E}[S_N]$ is clearly a more complicated object, it must be a function of $N$.

However, if $S_n : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is a random variable for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $N$ is a random variable taking values in $\mathbb{N}$, then one can form the random variable $S_N : \tilde{\Omega} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. The crucial point is that the sample spaces $\Omega$ and $\tilde{\Omega}$ are not the same!

Indeed, we could take $\Omega$ to be the product space generated by the $X_i$, namely $\Omega = \mathbb{Z}^n$. In this case, $\omega = \Omega$ encodes the values taken for $n$ flips. If $X_i$ were Bernoulli ($X_i= $ 0 or 1), then a typical $\omega$ might look like $\omega = (0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)$ (here $n = 8$). Notice that if we have $\omega$, then we can compute $S_n$ (in other words, if we know the values $X_i$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$, we can compute $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$).

However, the sample space $\tilde{\Omega}$ must be strictly larger. For any $\tilde{\omega} \in \tilde{\Omega}$, $\tilde{\omega}$ must encode which $n$ was chosen (according to the distribution of $N$). If $N$ is unbounded, then we might need infinitely many copies of $X_i$! A typical construction of $\tilde{\Omega}$ might be that we take $\tilde{\omega} = (n, 1, 0, 0, 1, \dots )$, where the first coordinate tells us which $n$ was chosen, and the coordinates after are the values of $X_1, X_2, \dots$.

Exercise:
Suppose 
$$N = \begin{cases} 1 & p = 1/3 \\ 3 & p = 2/3, \end{cases}$$
and let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be Bernoulli with $p = 1/2$. Find an $\Omega$ with the least number of elements such that, if you give me any $\omega$, you can tell me $S_1(\omega), S_2(\omega), S_3(\omega)$ and $S_N(\omega)$.

Comment: "The problem you have asked ... arguably motivates the foundations of probability" Wow, easy boy, easy...

Comment: Haha, okay, I definitely yield.